# Unable to download Adobe Premiere Elements v10 trial

Tags: download, adobe-premiere

I've been trying to download the trial of Adobe Premiere Elements v10 for hours, and it's driving me crazy. I tried both Adobe Download Manager and direct links ([file](http://prodesigntools.com/trials2/AdobeProducts/PRE/10/win64/PremiereElements_10_LS15_win64.7z) and [extractor](http://prodesigntools.com/trials2/AdobeProducts/PRE/10/win64/PremiereElements_10_LS15_win64.exe), found [here](http://prodesigntools.com/photoshop-elements-10-direct-download-links-pse-premiere-pre.html)), and both fail.

Adobe DLM tells me there was an error 101 (which is supposed to happen when no more disk space is available, which is not the case for me), and WinRAR gives me a CRC check error on the directly downloaded archive.

Is anybody experiencing the same issue? Are Adobe files corrupted, or is the problem on my side? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Download directly from Adobe's site: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=premiere_elements&loc=en_us